# How do I get only one result from a query without having to do a loop

Tags: php, mysql

How do I get back only one row in my query search using mysqli_

I've been reading about here:
[Here](https://cameronspear.com/blog/get-a-single-value-from-mysql-database-in-one-line-of-php/)

where it says that I can do a query like this:

```
$name = $mysqli->query("SELECT name FROM contacts WHERE id = 5")->fetch_object()->name;
```

but it does not work for me.

this is what I have:

$connection= mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "my_db");

using the same principle as the one in the page:

```
echo $result = $connection->query("SELECT organization FROM organizations_table WHERE status !=0 AND token=".$TOKEN)->fetch_object()->organization;
```

I suppose `fetch_object()->organization;` is the name of my table field.

Or is there a better way to do this, not that this way is working for me.
I'm using procedural php with mysqli_

Comment: one row is all you'll ever get from a single fetch() call. So... simply DON'T use a loop. call fetch() once, and done. And don't chain DB calls. it assumes that nothing will ever go wrong. run your query, check for failure, THEN fetch data.

Comment: `but it does not work for me.` Could you be more specific?

Comment: You may want to check for an sql error with `echo mysqli_error($mysqli);` in your code.

Comment: i get this error  `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on boolean in`

Comment: So there you go. your query failed, and since your code simply ASSUMED success, everything else broke. And note that you're NOT using "procedural mysqli". you're using OOP calls.

Comment: @learningbyexample So in your case, your SQL is wrong. Follow Proger_Cbsk's advice and use mysqli_error to see what's wrong.

Comment: Well, what about NOT assigning and echoing in the same time ? `$result = <query>;` THEN `echo $result;`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `mysqli_fetch_row()`. It will return only one result for your query.

Answer (score 0):

[`mysql::query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php), if successful, returns a [`mysqli_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object, which in turn provides method [`mysqli_result::fetch_object`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php).

> **Return Values**
>   Returns an object with string properties that corresponds to the fetched row or NULL if there are no more rows in resultset.

So spelled out

```
$result = $connection->query("...");
$row = $result->fetch_object();
$org = $row->organization;
```

can be shortened to

```
$org = $connection->query("...")->fetch_object()->organization;
```

*if* the query doesn't return false, because of some failure, and there are any rows, so `fetch_object` can return an object.